# Error en localhost mysql con xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Buenas noches usuarios, soy nuevo en la programacion y en clase tenemos todos el mismo problema, tengo instalado **MY SQL WORKBENCH 6.3** Y **XAMPP**, inicio de xampp para mysql okey, pero cuando intengo conectarme a mi localhost que me aparace en el workbench me da este error :

> incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocolo
>   detected (10.1.21).

ya googlie y la verdad no se que puede ser, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de XAMPP tienes?

Comment: perdon, me olvide de especificar eso, es la version v3.2.2

Comment: Aquí te dejo un link que esta en ingles pero que tiene  una buena explicación a tu problema [ir al enlace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252275/mysql-workbench-warning-when-connecting-to-mariadb)

Comment: buenisimo, ya lo leo, muchas gracias, si me anda te aviso.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez, deberías poner esa URL como respuesta y no como comentario (agregando algo de literatura para completar). Cuenta con mi voto cuando lo hagas.

Comment: Hola buenos días voy a preparar la respuesta para colocarla.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te esta sucediendo es un problema ***potencial*** de compatibilidad. ***Mysql Workbench*** es un producto ***Oracle***  y ***MariaDB*** no.

Aquí te dejo el link donde te da una explica de forma detallada lo que te esta sucediendo.

[Ir al enlace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252275/mysql-workbench-warning-when-connecting-to-mariadb)

Texto citado en la respuesta aceptada del enlace, la lista de incompatibilidades de cada versión se encuentran en la página de MariaDB:

> [MariaDB es un descendiente binario en reemplazo de MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/es/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/)
>
> Para todos los propósitos practicos, **MariaDB es un descendiente binario en reemplazo de la misma versión de MySQL**. (Por ejemplo MySQl 5.1 -> MariaDB 5.1, MariaDB 5.2 & MariaDB 5.3 son compatibles. MySQL 5.5 sera compatible con MariaDB 5.5). Lo que esto significa que:
>
> - La definición de datos y tablas en archivos (.frm) son archivos
>     binarios compatibles.
> - Todas las APIs de clientes, protocolos y estructuras son idénticas.
> - Todos los nombre de archivos, binarios, rutas, puertos, sockets, etc. deben ser los mismos.
> - Todos los conectores MySQL (Conectores como los de PHP, Perl, Python, Java,
>     .NET, MyODBC, Ruby, MySQL, C, etc.) trabajan sin cambios con MariaDB.
> - Hay algunos problemas de instalación de PHP5 con los que debería
>     tener precaución (como en el antigüo cliente de PHP5 que marcaba un
>     error de compatibilidad con la libreria).
> - El paquete mysql-client también trabaja con MariaDB server.
> - La librería de cliente compartida es binaria-mente compatible con la librería cliente de MySQL.
>
> Esto significa que para muchos casos, puedes solo des-instalar MySQL e instalar MariaDB y estarás listo para comenzar. (No necesitas convertir ningún archivo de datos si usas la misma versión, como la 5.1).
>
> **Hacemos comparaciones mensuales con el código fuente de MySQL** para estar seguros que continuamos con compatibilidad y tenemos todas las características y arreglos de errores añadidos por Oracle.
>
> También hemos hecho un montón de trabajo en los scripts de actualización hasta el punto de que ahora es más fácil actualizar desde MySQL 5.0 a MariaDB 5.1 que de MySQL 5.0 a MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score -1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Es porque estan el usando el mismo puerto para escuchar.
En Xamp cambia el puerto uno que tengas libre
en conf- apache y donde tienes el 80 pon el 8080

Comment: aunque de el aviso de incompatibilidad funciona correctamente, solo te avisa, adjunto fotos

Comment: Nose quien da puntos negativos sin decir una explicación, mejor o segun el si dice que no es correcta que la corrija, como se ve que la conexión si se establece y funciona